# SQLite difference between two sets

Tags: sql, sqlite, set

I have a table with:

```
sqlite> select * from lookup;
node|id
1|1
1|2
2|4
2|6
sqlite> select * from tag;
tagid|data
1|bar
2|baz
3|geek
4|foo
5|bank
6|auto
```

I would like to find the id's in the tag table which are not referred in lookup. 
I tried with:

```
select id from tag where not exists (select tagid from lookup);
# I am expecting the following result: 3, 5
```

But this returns nothing. `tagid` is a foriegn key to `tag`, could this the source of the problem? Can you give a hint how to do this in SQL?

Comment: Uhm, if `tagid` is a foreign key to `tag`, why is it in the same table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correlate the two queries. As you have it you are just asking whether nothing exists in the lookup table.

```
select 
    id 
from 
    tag t
where 
    not exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            lookup l
        where
            l.tagid = t.id -- correlation
    );
```

You can also write this using an outer join

```
select
    t.id
from
    tag t
        left outer join
    lookup l
        on t.id = l.tagid
where
    l.tagid is null;
```

Some databases have different performance characteristics for the two methods.

To delete:

```
delete from
    tag
where
    not exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            lookup l
        where
            l.tagid = tag.id
    );
```

Comment: BTW, how can you expand this to directly deleting?

Comment: The delete statement gives me an error. `DELETE FROM TAG WHERE ID in (select id from tag  t where not exists (select id from lookup l where l.tagid = t.id)` did work though.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for ids from the tag table, but your select uses ids from the lookup table.
You have to select tagids from the tag table such that those tagids are NOT in the set of ids from the lookup table:

```
select tagid from tag where tagid not in (select id from lookup);
```

Comment: can you please format your select queries? It's easier to understand what you mean like that.